# Convert C++ struct to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have a C++ struct below:

```
struct CUSTOM_DATA {
   int id;
   u_short port;
   unsigned long ip;
} custom_data;
```

How can i convert it to C# struct, serialize it and send via tcp socket?

Thanks!

**upd**

So C# code will be?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CustomData
{
 public int id;
 public ushort port;
 public uint ip;
}

public void Send()
{
 CustomData d = new CustomData();
 d.id = 12;
 d.port = 1000;
 d.ip = BitConverter.ToUInt32(IPAddress.Any.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
 IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(d));
 Marshal.StructureToPtr(d, pointer, false);
 byte[] data_to_send = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(d)];
 Marshal.Copy(pointer, data_to_send, 0, data_to_send.Length);
 client.GetStream().Write(data_to_send, 0, data_to_send.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The C# version of this struct would be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CustomData
{
    public int id;
    public ushort port;
    public uint ip;
}
```

As for sending this via a socket, you can just send the binary data directly.  The [Marshal class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) has methods for getting a pointer (IntPtr) from the structure and copying into a byte array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you help me, is all ok with my code about copying to buffer and sending it?

Comment: @Becker You should use StructureToPtr, not GetComInterfaceForObject.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx#Y1000

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, i just never done things like this before. I edited my code, now all ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct CUSTOM_DATA {
   int id;
   ushort port;
   uint ip;
};
CUSTOM_DATA cData ; // use me
```

***edit:*** thx reed

Comment: It should be uint, not ulong - A C++ "unsigned long" is 4 bytes, ie: UInt32 in C#