# where to declare the contents of a header file in C# Win Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, compact-framework

I know there is no header files concept in C#. I created a header file with some definitions and structures for c++ project.

Now I need to develop the same project using C#, In C# how can we declare the contents of that header file. I need to use those header file contents for entire project in C#.

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert C++ struct to C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838825/convert-c-struct-to-c-sharp)

Comment: thats ok sir.. but Where to declare those contents in C# ??? so that I can use it for entire C# project.

Comment: You can create a dll and import it anywhere you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're already noticed, there isn't a Header concept for C#. Stuff that you normally define in C++ headers is packed into normal class files (*.cs) in C#, e.g. enum and stuff. You'd better be creating an own class file for each class. Use Visual Studios Folders to separate the .cs files by concern. This will normally also be reflected in the namespaces. To Access classes from different namespaces, use the "using" keyword in C#.

HTH,
alex